# Retrieve the controller name from a class name following RoR conventions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, controller, naming-conventions

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.0.9 and I would like to build a controller name from a class name as well as possible following RoR naming conventions. For example, if I have the `Articles::Comment` class I would like to retrieve the `articles/comments` string.

Maybe it exists a RoR method created by developers to handle internally these conventions, but I don't know that.

**How can I retrieve the controller name as in the example above?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the underscore method. [More info here](http://as.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/String/Inflections.html#M000383).

```
"Articles::Comment".underscore
```

Or, if you've got the controller class itself, it would be like this:

```
Articles::Comment.name.underscore
```

**EDIT**

As of routes, they are built one piece at a time, even when you namespace them. When you do something like this:

```
map.resources :articles do |articles|
  articles.resources :comments
end
```

What rails is going to do is, first:

```
"articles". classify # which yields "Article" then rails is going to append "Controller" to it
```

Then it's going to get "comments" and do the same, but this one is going to be routed under "/articles". Rails does not namespace internal resources, so, the controller has to be CommentsController, not Articles::CommentsController.

Only then you clearly namespace something, Rails is going to namespace your classes:

```
map.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.resources :articles # will require controller "Admin::ArticlesController"
end
```

I hope it's clearer now.

Comment: Using your code I will need to call also the 'pluralize' method... however is this how RoR internally handle these naming conventions?

Comment: Looks like I got your question wrong, I did not notice the plural, this is how Rails generates names for paths, as in articles_comment_path, not for routes. On routes each piece is it's own name, that's the class name tableize'd.